# Bash function arguments

Tags: bash

My problem is that `prepinace_grepu`, which is `$3` inside of function,  evaluates  to  `-i` instead of `-i -n` as I expected it to be .
How can I change it to work? And I cant put it in two variables, because I want it to be flexible and just take it as a string , so it will work even if `prepinace_grepu="-c -v -i -f"`  etc...

```
compare()
{
semka $2 $1 /etc/passwd /etc/shadow | sort > result1.txt
grep $3 $1 /etc/passwd /etc/shadow | sort > result2.txt
diff result2.txt result1.txt > diff.txt

if [[ -s diff.txt ]] ; 
    then echo "FAIL"
else echo "OK"
fi ;
 }

pattern=Hojny 
prepinace_moje="-vi"
prepinace_grepu="-i -n" 
compare $pattern $prepinace_moje $prepinace_grepu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the variables in shell as much as you can:

```
pattern="Hojny"
prepinace_moje="-vi"
prepinace_grepu="-i -n" 
compare "$pattern" "$prepinace_moje" "$prepinace_grepu"
```

Since `prepinace_grepu` contains space you must send it in quotes otherwise called function will only get `-i` and `$3` and `-n` as `$4`.

Comment: also it would be safe to enclose $1 , $2 and $3 with double quotes when grepping

Comment: In general, you need a very good reason *not* to quote a parameter expansion.

Comment: @chepner is right, just quote **EVERYTHING**. Some time later you will learn when you can omit quotes, but extra quotes never hurt.

It should be also pointed out that ``$1``, ``$2`` and ``$3`` inside the function should be quoted as well, otherwise it might result in very interesting results for some complicated patterns. If you want ``prepinace_grepu`` to contain a list of parameters, then just use array and pass it like ``"${prepinace_grepu[@]}"``

Comment: Extra quotes hurt only when you are trying to stuff commands (or command arguments) into a string (like is being done here). And they hurt exactly because you shouldn't be doing that. Quoting `$3` in the function here may very well hurt the usage with `grep` but that's because, as stated, that is stuffing arguments into a string.

Comment: Here's an example of a good reason to not quote an expansion: when you store a pattern in a variable for the pattern match operator `=` inside `[[ ... ]]`.  When you write something like `x=foo*; if [[ $somevariable = $x ]]; then ...`, the value of `$somevariable` is compared against the *pattern* `foo*`, which could match `foo`, `foobar`, `foo123`, etc. If you quote `$x`, then strict string equality is performed, and the test will succeed only if `$somevariable` has the literal value `foo*`.

Comment: just to give u more info, inside of SEMKA which is my C program where i tried to implement/mimic real GREP, and in that C program i then use getopt() to deal with program's options, and btw prepinace_moje==my_options in my language, and prepinace_grepu==grep_options :D

Comment: Except in this case, you do NOT want to quote $3 for grep, since `"-i -n"` is an invalid option